# acumatica save excel export user and password

Tags: excel, acumatica

I can export a generic inquiry to excel workbook on my laptop and then refresh data (data ---refresh all). A pop up window appears with Windows Security (excel.exe) that ask for acumatica user and password. I enter this and tick the box to "remember my credentials" and save workbook. However next time when I open my workbook and try to refresh from cloud credentials are needed to enter again. Is there any way to save the credentials so workbook can be refreshed without user and password?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's Excel setting.
Try next approach - use as user next structure username@company